# Join Table and fill null column with return table value

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have two tables as below

```
TableA
A_id    name
----    ----
123     Test1   
124     Test2
125     Test3
126     Test4

TableB
B_id    fk_A_id    value     type_id
----    -------    -----     -------
1       123        op1       1
2       123        hello     2
3       123        abc       3
4       126        op2       1
5       126        hello     2
6       126        def       3
```

i use query to join both table

```
select TableA.A_id as id, TableA.name as name, TBL2.type_name as type_name
from TableA
full join (
select fk_A_id, value as type_name
from TableB
where type_id = 2
)TBL2 on TableA.A_id = TBL2.fk_A_id
```

the return result would be

```
id            name            type_name
--            ----            ---------
123           Test1           hello
124           Test2             
125           Test3
126           Test4           hello
```

my question is how i fill the null column with 'hello' as well which is the return result from TableB, the type_id = '2' will have similar string across that TableB

Comment: I'm not completely understanding.  Why would you want to fill `null` column with `hello`?  Are you assuming `type_id=2` will always return `hello`?  If so, that would be a different query using a `cross join` instead.

Comment: yes, the data itself for type_id=2 will be also 'hello'

Comment: If you know it's always `hello`, why not just use `hello`?  If it's dynamic based on the `type_id`, then you should use a `cross join`.  However, your sample data doesn't suggest the `type_id` is always the same per `value`...

Comment: yes, i underdstand what you mean, somehow the database design is few years back and the type_id = 2 now suppostedly is fixed value every time and may not change, in this case, it should not design as such, but i have to query it to join with other table and fill those null column with 'hello'

Comment: So easiest solution perhaps, `select id, name, 'hello' from tablea` -- if you know that `hello` is always the value, why bother querying for it?

Comment: because the result table will generate as pivot table, if the null coloumn is not fill the pivot table will have two parent node 'hello' and null, i only want the pivot table to have one parent node which is 'hello' and child which is Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4 (all these actually belongs to hello)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `left join`, like this:

```
select a.A_id as id, a.name as name, b.type_name as type_name
from TableA a left join
     TableB b
     on a.A_id = b.fk_A_id and b.type_id = 2;
```

There is no need for a subquery and the `full join` is overkill.

If you want the `NULL` value to also be `hello`, use `coalesce()`:

```
select a.A_id as id, a.name as name,
       coalesce(b.type_name, 'hello') as type_name
from TableA a left join
     TableB b
     on a.A_id = b.fk_A_id and b.type_id = 2;
```

Comment: yes, tried your query, seems giving same result, but i wanted to fill the null column with hello